# Can't install the webcam driver of dell inspiron n4030

Tags: windows-7, laptop, webcam, dell-inspiron

I have my laptop running windows 7 32bit and I want to use my webcam, I tried searching dell.com  for drivers using TagService of my machine but didn't find any drivers for webcam,
I've tried installing programs like Webcam management center but didn't complete. 
Finally I opened "Device Manager"-->Imaging devices-->Integrated webcam and the device status was "This device is working properly"

In fact I don't know what to do.. any help please.

Comment: could you paste here the lines that appears in "Device Manager > Imaging Devices > Integrated Webcam > Properties > Details > Hardware Id"?

Comment: there are two Ids:

USB\VID_0C45&PID_6488&REV_1120&MI_00 ------AND-------

USB\VID_0C45&PID_6488&MI_00

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Webcam driver of [your Dell](http://devid.info/es/model/8031) is managed by Microsoft, try to update it with [this version](http://devid.info/p157892) but be aware that it's outdated (2006-06-21) and may not work.

The integrated options of Windows Update or from `Device Manager` >  `Imaging Devices` >  `Integrated Webcam` > `Properties` > `Controler` > `Update Controller` > `Update from Windows Update` should give you the newest driver available.

Some search with the hardware driver related me to [drivers.adwit](http://drivers.awdit.com/vid_0c45/integrated-webcam-2/) and it seems that it isn't a standalone driver and depends of some other like `usb.inf`, `usbccgp.sys`, `usbvideo.inf` that are managed too by Microsoft.

If this don't work, try updating [EHCI](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-14-n4030?driverId=DPN8F&osCode=W764&fileId=2731094231) and the [BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-14-n4030?driverId=V2NHN&osCode=W764&fileId=2731101050) and check that you have no options in BIOS and in keyboard that don't allow you to use the camera.

If nothing works, install [Dell System Software](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-14-n4030?driverId=MTF9M&osCode=W764&fileId=2731094033), it should search all the drivers for your computer, if something is missing it will install.

Comment: I've tried installing Dell System Software but there was an error ---> "This installation package is not supported by this processor type. contact your product vendor"


I've tried updating driver software from device manager-->integrated webcam but the message was " Windows was determined the driver software for your device is up to date"

any other way?

Comment: had you tried with the driver from devid? (the second link), have you checked the BIOS options?

Comment: I didn't got it, would you please explain in details how to check the BIOS options, and how to try with the driver from devid?

Comment: for the bios options, reboot your computer, in the first image of dell you'll see press F2, you'll enter in the BIOS. Check all the options, it has to be in some menu like "Integrated devices". Download the driver from devid http://devid.info/download/30829/24 and install it.

Comment: I searched this website for a driver for the webcam but didn't find it http://devid.info/en/model/8031, now i'll try with the bios

Comment: I pressed F2 and entered the BIOS, entered advanced, and all were enabled.. 
any new move?

Comment: it's there but you don't see it... http://devid.info/en/model/8031 image > usb video device...